# How to localize parts of time in C#

Tags: localization

I want to add a label beside a spinner control to indicate the unit, eg, "hours" or "minutes" and have it localized to "horas" in Spanish or 小时 in Chinese automatically by the application (without having to add the label into a resource file).

What should I set the Text property of the label to?